# What are some French words derived from Arabic?

Tags: emprunts, arabe

I learned that Spanish, due to the history, has a number of Arabic loanwords. Among them: *ojala que* and *azucar* . What about French? are some French words derived from Arabic?

Comment: Yes, there are many. [Here's one list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_words_of_Arabic_origin)

Comment: @PapaPoule I think any answer from now on would derive from your link. Maybe you should be the one to post it, giving some example, note that some of them are derived from Spanish words derived from Arabic (that adds a link with the question)... I think you deserve that rep! :)

Comment: La liste _Wikipédia_ contient des éléments qui ne sont pas présents dans la liste de la réponse (l'emprunt direct vs. mot tiré de (?), par exemple [_algèbre_](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/alg%C3%A8bre)). Il serait bien d'avoir plus d'une réponse.

Comment: @Chop Thanks for your kind words!  However, the only two that I know/think I knew are slang ('bled' & '[pas] besef') so I was basically just providing a "let me Google that for you" kind of "answer" here in the comment section (without expecting/deserving anything) after seeing it go unanswered for several hours (I guess I forgot about the 6-hour time difference when thinking that it might remain totally unanswered). Gam Pub's answer is certainly good & got my vote, although Riquefort is correct in stating that, as always, the more answers, the better (I just don't know enough to offer one).

Answer (score 8):

From the *TLFi*, the largest reference dictionary for French, you can extract borrowings from this [page](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/showps.exe?p=combi.htm;java=no;). Click "*Recherche complexe*" at the top, then in the form select "*Langue empruntée*" in the first drop-down menu (*type de l'objet*), and type "*arabe*" in the last column field (*contenu*):

- [BAOBAB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BAOBAB), subst. masc.
- [BARAQUER2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BARAQUER), verbe trans.
- [BARBACANE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BARBACANE), subst. fém.
- [BARDE2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BARDE), subst. fém.
- [BEN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BEN), subst. masc.
- [BONDUC](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BONDUC), subst. masc.
- [BORAX](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BORAX), subst. masc.
- [BOURACAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BOURACAN), subst. masc.
- [BOURDE3](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/BOURDE), subst. fém.
- [CACHEF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CACHEF), subst. masc.
- [CAFRE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CAFRE), CAFFRE, adj. et subst.
- [CAÏD](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CA%C3%8FD), subst. masc.
- [CALIBRE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CALIBRE), subst. masc.
- [CALIFE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CALIFE), KHALIFE, subst. masc.
- [CAMELOT1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CAMELOT), subst. masc.
- [CANDI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CANDI), adj. masc.
- [CANGE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CANGE), subst. fém.
- [CAOUA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CAOUA), subst. masc.
- [CARAQUE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CARAQUE), CARRAQUE, subst. fém. et adj.
- [CASBAH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CASBAH), subst. fém.
- [CAVAS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CAVAS), CAWAS, subst. masc.
- [CHADOUF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHADOUF), subst. masc.
- [CHEBEC](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHEBEC), CHÉBEC, CHEBEK, subst. masc.
- [CHÈCHE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CH%C3%88CHE), subst. masc.
- [CHÉCHIA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CH%C3%89CHIA), subst. fém.
- [CHEIK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHEIK)(H), subst. masc.
- [CHÉRIF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CH%C3%89RIF), SCHÉRIF, subst. masc.
- [CHERVIS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHERVIS), subst. masc.
- [CHIBOUQUE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHIBOUQUE), subst. fém., CHIBOUK, subst. masc.
- [CHIFFRE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHIFFRE), subst. masc.
- [CHLEU](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHLEU)(H), adj.
- [CHOTT](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHOTT), subst. masc.
- [CHOUIA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CHOUIA), CHOUÏA, CHOUYA, adv.
- [CIVETTE2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CIVETTE), subst. fém.
- [CLEBS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CLEBS), subst. masc.
- [CORAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CORAN), KORAN, subst. masc.
- [COTON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/COTON), subst. masc.
- [COURBACH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/COURBACH), subst. masc.; COURBACHE, subst. fém.
- [COUSCOUS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/COUSCOUS)(S), COUSCOUSSOU, subst. masc.
- [CUBÈBE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CUB%C3%88BE), subst. masc.
- [CURCUMA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CURCUMA), subst. masc.
- [CUSCUTE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/CUSCUTE), subst. fém.
- [DAHABIEH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DAHABIEH), subst. fém.
- [DAHIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DAHIR), subst. masc.
- [DAMAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DAMAN), subst. masc.
- [DARABOUK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DARABOUK), subst. masc.; DARBOUKA(H), subst. fém.
- [DINAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DINAR), subst. masc.
- [DJEBEL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DJEBEL), subst. masc.
- [DJELLABA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DJELLABA)(H), subst. fém.
- [DJINN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DJINN), subst. masc.
- [DOUAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DOUAR), subst. masc.
- [DOUM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DOUM), subst. masc.
- [DOURA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/DOURA)(H), subst. fém.
- [ÉLÉMI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%89L%C3%89MI), subst. masc.
- [ÉLIXIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%89LIXIR), subst. masc.
- [ÉMIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%89MIR), subst. masc.
- [ÉPINARD](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%89PINARD), subst. masc.
- [ERG1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ERG), subst. masc.
- [ESTRAGON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ESTRAGON), subst. masc.
- [FAKIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FAKIR), FAQUIR, subst. masc
- [FARDE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FARDE), subst. fém.
- [FELLAG](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FELLAG)(H)A, subst. masc.
- [FELLAH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FELLAH), subst.
- [FETFA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FETFA), subst. masc.
- [FISSA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FISSA), adv.
- [FLOUZE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FLOUZE), subst. masc.
- [FONDOUK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FONDOUK), subst. masc.
- [FOUTA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/FOUTA)(H), subst. masc. ou fém.
- [GANDOURA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GANDOURA)(H), subst. fém.
- [GAZELLE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GAZELLE), subst. fém.
- [GENETTE2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GENETTE), subst. fém.
- [GERBOISE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GERBOISE), subst. fém.
- [GHAZEL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GHAZEL), subst. masc.
- [GILET](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GILET), subst. masc.
- [GOUDRON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GOUDRON), subst. masc.
- [GOULE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GOULE), subst. fém.
- [GOUM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GOUM), subst. masc.
- [GOUR1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GOUR), subst. masc.
- [GOURBI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GOURBI), subst. masc.
- [GUIMBRI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GUIMBRI), subst. masc.
- [GUITOUNE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/GUITOUNE), subst. fém.
- [HACHISCH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HACHISCH), HASCHICH, HACHICH, subst. masc.
- [HADÎTH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HAD%C3%8ETH), subst. masc.
- [HADJ1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HADJ), subst. masc.
- [HAÏK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HA%C3%8FK), subst. masc.
- [HAMADA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HAMADA),subst. fém.
- [HAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HAM)(M)AL, subst. masc.
- [HAMMAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HAMMAM), subst. masc.
- [HAREM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HAREM), subst. masc.
- [HARISSA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HARISSA), subst. fém.
- [HARKA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HARKA), subst. fém.
- [HASARD](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HASARD), subst. masc.
- [HOQUETON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/HOQUETON), subst. masc.
- [IMAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/IMAM), IMAN, subst. masc.
- [ISLAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ISLAM), subst. masc.
- [JARRE1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/JARRE), subst. fém.
- [JASMIN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/JASMIN), subst. masc.
- [KABYLE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KABYLE), adj. et subst.
- [KAFIR](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/kafir), subst. masc.
- [KALI1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KALI), subst. masc.
- [KANDJAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KANDJAR), CANGIAR, subst. masc.
- [KANOUN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KANOUN), subst. masc.
- [KERMÈS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KERM%C3%88S), subst. masc.
- [KETMIE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KETMIE), subst. fém.
- [KHAMMÈS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KHAMM%C3%88S), subst. masc.
- [KHAMSIN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KHAMSIN), subst. masc.
- [KIBLA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KIBLA), subst. fém.
- [KIEF2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KIEF), KIF, subst. masc.
- [KIF-KIF](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KIF-KIF), KIF, adj. inv.
- [KOHL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KOHL), subst. masc.
- [KOUBBA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KOUBBA), subst. fém.
- [KRAK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KRAK), subst. masc.
- [KROUMIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KROUMIR), subst. masc.
- [KSAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/KSAR), subst. masc.
- [LAGMI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LAGMI), LAGMY, subst. masc.
- [LAITON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LAITON), subst. masc.
- [LAQUE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LAQUE), subst.
- [LILAS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LILAS), subst. masc. et adj.
- [LITHAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LITHAM), subst. masc.
- [LOOCH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LOOCH), subst. masc.
- [LUTH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/LUTH), subst. masc.
- [MABOUL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MABOUL), MABOULE, adj. et subst.
- [MACACHE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MACACHE), adv.
- [MADRAGUE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MADRAGUE), subst. fém.
- [MAGASIN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MAGASIN), subst. masc.
- [MAGHRÉBIN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MAGHR%C3%89BIN), -INE, adj. et subst.
- [MAHDI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MAHDI), subst. masc.
- [MAÏDAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MA%C3%8FDAN), subst. masc.
- [MAKHZEN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MAKHZEN), MAGHZEN, subst. masc.
- [MAMELOUK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MAMELOUK), MAMELUK, subst. masc. et adj.
- [MASSER2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MASSER), verbe trans.
- [MASTABA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MASTABA), subst. masc.
- [MATAMORE2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MATAMORE), subst. masc.
- [MATRAQUE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MATRAQUE), subst. fém.
- [MÉCHOUAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89CHOUAR), subst. masc.
- [MÉCHOUI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89CHOUI), subst. masc.
- [MECHTA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MECHTA), subst. fém.
- [MÉDIN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89DIN), subst. masc.
- [MÉDINA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89DINA), subst. fém.
- [MÉHALLA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89HALLA), subst. fém.
- [MÉHARI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/M%C3%89HARI), subst. masc.
- [MEKTOUB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MEKTOUB), interj.
- [MERGUEZ](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MERGUEZ), subst. fém.
- [MIHRAB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MIHRAB), subst. masc.
- [MINBAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MINBAR), subst. masc.
- [MOLLAH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MOLLAH), subst. masc.
- [MOUCHARABY](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MOUCHARABY), MOUCHARABIEH, subst. masc.
- [MOUD](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MOUD)(H)IR, subst. masc.
- [MUCHIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MUCHIR), subst. masc.
- [MUFTI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/MUFTI), MUPHTI, subst. masc.
- [NACAIRE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NACAIRE), subst. fém.
- [NADIR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NADIR), subst. masc.
- [NAFFE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NAFFE), subst. fém.
- [NATRON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NATRON), NATRUM, subst. masc.
- [NAZIR2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NAZIR), subst. masc.
- [NEBKA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NEBKA), subst. fém.
- [NEDJDI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NEDJDI), NEDJI, subst. masc.
- [NIZERÉ](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NIZER%C3%89), subst. masc.
- [NOUBA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/NOUBA), subst. fém.
- [OTTOMAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/OTTOMAN), -ANE, adj. et subst.
- [OUED](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/OUED), subst. masc.
- [RAÏS2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/RA%C3%8FS), subst. masc.
- [RAMDAM](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/RAMDAM), subst. masc.
- [RAQUETTE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/RAQUETTE), subst. fém.
- [RAZZIA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/RAZZIA), subst. fém.
- [RÉALGAR](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/R%C3%89ALGAR), subst. masc.
- [REBAB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/REBAB), , subst. masc.
- [REG](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/REG), subst. masc.
- [REZZOU](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/REZZOU), subst. masc.
- [ROB1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ROB), subst. masc.
- [ROC2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ROC), subst. masc.
- [ROCK1](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ROCK), subst. masc.
- [ROMAINE2](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ROMAINE), subst. fém.
- [ROUMI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ROUMI), subst. masc.
- [SAHEL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SAHEL), subst. masc.
- [SAKIEH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SAKIEH), subst. fém.
- [SALAMALEC](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SALAMALEC), subst. masc.
- [SAPHÈNE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SAPH%C3%88NE), adj.
- [SAROUAL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SAROUAL), SAROUEL, , subst. masc.
- [SEBKHA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SEBKHA), subst. fém.
- [SÉGUIA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/S%C3%89GUIA), SEGHIA, subst. fém.
- [SERDAB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SERDAB), subst. masc.
- [SESBANIA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SESBANIA), subst. masc.
- [SIDI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SIDI), subst. masc.
- [SIGLATON](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SIGLATON), subst. masc.
- [SIMOUN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SIMOUN), subst. masc.
- [SLOUGHI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SLOUGHI), subst. masc.
- [SMALA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SMALA)(H), subst. fém.
- [SOUDAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SOUDAN), subst. masc.
- [SOUFI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SOUFI), subst. masc.
- [SOUK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SOUK), subst. masc.
- [SULTAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SULTAN), subst. masc.
- [SUNNA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SUNNA), subst. fém.
- [SURATE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/SURATE), SOURATE, subst. fém.
- [TABI](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TABI), subst. masc.
- [TABIS](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TABIS), subst. masc.
- [TABOULÉ](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TABOUL%C3%89), subst. masc.
- [TAJINE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TAJINE), subst. masc.
- [TALC](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TALC), subst. masc.
- [TALMOUSE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TALMOUSE), subst. fém.
- [TARABOUK](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TARABOUK), subst. masc.
- [TARBOUCH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TARBOUCH)(E), subst. masc.
- [TASSE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TASSE), subst. fém.
- [TELL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TELL), subst. masc.
- [TOUBIB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TOUBIB), subst. masc.
- [TRUCHEMENT](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TRUCHEMENT), subst. masc.
- [TURBITH](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TURBITH), subst. masc.
- [TUT](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/TUT)(H)IE, subst. fém.
- [USNÉE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/USN%C3%89E), subst. fém.
- [VARAN](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/VARAN), subst. masc.
- [ZAOUÏA](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ZAOU%C3%8FA), subst. fém.
- [ZELLIGE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ZELLIGE), subst. masc.
- [ZERUMBET](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/zerumbet), subst. masc.
- [ZOB](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ZOB), ZOB(B)I, subst. masc. et interj.
- [ZOUAVE](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ZOUAVE), subst. masc.